# RegExp: Match first 3 char words

Tags: regex

/[\w|A-Z]{1,3}[a-z]/g
but I want to match only the first 3 char of words.
For example:

```
I WANt THE FIRst 3 CHAr OF WORds ONLy.
```

It's for a rapid lector: only uppercase the begining of any words.

The best could be: (First 3 char)(Rest of the word or space)

https://regex101.com/r/PCi8Dn/2

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Original answer

Use positive lookahead (`(?=[pattern]`) to match without including in the match.

```
[A-Z]{1,3}(?=[a-z])
```

appears to do what you want (if I've understood your spec correctly).

You can see it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/VNEiSc/1).

### New answer following clarification on spec

I think this does what you want:

```
(\S{1,3})(\S*[\s\.]+)
```

The breakdown is:

- **1st capturing group:** `(\S{1,3})`

Matches a maximum of 3 non-space characters (`\S` used instead of `\w` because I think you want to match characters with diacritics like `à` and punctuation in the middle of words like `'`.

- **2nd capturing group**: `(\S*[\s\.]+)`

Matches zero or more non-space characters (the remaining characters in each word) followed by one or more delimiter characters (space or period). I included period as a delimiter to match the last word. You might want to adjust that part depending on your exact needs.

See it in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/hcciFc/1).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/PCi8Dn/2 it's like this but I want: Group1 (3 char max) Group2 (rest of the word or space).
Thanks anyway !

Comment: Please see the new answer above, I hope it helps.